# Difference between basic and url base64 encoding in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, base64, uri

The Java 8 [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) library has two variants that can be used in URI building: the "Basic" one and the "URL and Filename safe". The documentation points to [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) Table 2 as an explanation for the differences.

After reading the spec it still isn't clear to me what the practical difference is between both encodings: are both standards "widely" supported? What about browsers specifically? Is the URL and filename safe encoding recommended for data URI encoding? Are there known support limitations?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way is to provide an example(IMHO):

```
    Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
    Base64.Encoder encURL = Base64.getUrlEncoder();

    byte[] bytes = enc.encode("subjects?_d".getBytes());
    byte[] bytesURL = encURL.encode("subjects?_d".getBytes());

    System.out.println(new String(bytes)); // c3ViamVjdHM/X2Q=      notice the "/"
    System.out.println(new String(bytesURL)); // c3ViamVjdHM_X2Q=   notice the "_"

    Base64.Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
    Base64.Decoder decURL = Base64.getUrlDecoder();

    byte[] decodedURL = decURL.decode(bytesURL);
    byte[] decoded = dec.decode(bytes);

    System.out.println(new String(decodedURL));
    System.out.println(new String(decoded));
```

Notice how one is `URL safe` and the other is not.

As a matter of fact if you look at the implementation, there are two look-up tables used for encoding: `toBase64` and `toBase64URL`. There are two characters only that differ for them:

`+` and `/` for `toBase64` versus `-` and `_` for `toBase64URL`.

So it seems that your question *is one URI safe and should be used there?*; the answer is yes.

Comment: So the assumption is that major browsers implement the URL-safe standard? MDN documentation for example does not specify this.

Comment: @vinntec I can't really say... but I would assume so looking at the implementation.

Comment: Actually Chrome can't interpret the URL safe one when put in a data URI, but can interpret the basic one.

Comment: @Eugene does it mean that I could just use base 64 encoder to encode and then replace + with - and / with _ and then the string will be same as the output of a base 64 URL encoder?  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Running some tests, encoding a data URI using base64 "URL and filename safe" produces URIs that are not recognised by Chrome.

Example: `data:text/plain;base64,TG9yZW0/aXBzdW0=` is properly decoded to `Lorem?ipsum`, while its URL-safe counterpart `data:text/plain;base64,TG9yZW0_aXBzdW0=` is not (ERR_INVALID_URL).

Comment: What if you try `data:text/plain;base64url,........`? I have never tried it before though. But it seems logical since the string you are providing is `base64url` encoded but you're telling chrome that it's `base64`.